# Jsoup save content into the database

Tags: java, jsoup

I have an array of urls, I want to store information from the url I read it in the database. My problem is the list of my data too large url if read serialize each url from above dew under stored in the database will take time.

I know there is a way to use thread to manipulate but I do not know how to do, please help me. Or whatever your method

```
try {
    String lstUrls = "http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Scala/index.htm\n"
            + "http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Scala/0020__Scala_Variables.htm\n"
            + "http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Scala/0040__Scala_Variable_Declarations.htm\n"
            + "http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Scala/0060__Scala_Semicolons.htm\n"
            + "http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Scala/0080__Scala_Code_Blocks.htm\n"
            + "http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Scala/0090__Scala_Comments.htm\n"
            + "http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Scala/0100__Scala_Type_Hierarchy.htm\n";
    String[] urls = lstUrls.split("\n");
    for (String url : urls) {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36").get();
        Elements select = doc.select("div.row");
        String html = select.html();
        System.out.println(html);
        /*
         insert html to database
         */
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: One thing you can do is queue the output and insert it as one batch in the database, so that you hit the database only once.

Comment: @Ma Tâm If my answer helped you, please consider upvoting it.

Comment: Thank turingcomplete I'am sorry, english is not my language,so I do not understand what you say,you should hope more detailed instructions or a document I need to learn .

Comment: That is of course :D thank you Hasanaga

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use multiple threads for retrieving the data, you can do something like this:

```
    Executor ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    String lstUrls = "http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Scala/index.htm\n"
            + "http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Scala/0020__Scala_Variables.htm\n"
            + "http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Scala/0040__Scala_Variable_Declarations.htm\n"
            + "http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Scala/0060__Scala_Semicolons.htm\n"
            + "http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Scala/0080__Scala_Code_Blocks.htm\n"
            + "http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Scala/0090__Scala_Comments.htm\n"
            + "http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Scala/0100__Scala_Type_Hierarchy.htm\n";
    String[] urls = lstUrls.split("\n");
    for (final String url : urls) {
        try {
            ex.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Document doc = Jsoup
                                .connect(url)
                                .userAgent(
                                        "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36")
                                .get();
                        Elements select = doc.select("div.row");
                        String html = select.html();
                        System.out.println(html);
                        /*
                         * insert html to database
                         */
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This will use 3 threads to process the urls concurrently, if you want to use more then 3 threads change this line `Executor ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);` and replace `3` with whatever number you want.

You can find out more about [Executors here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Comment: It's great, I thought to do a lot more complex.I will learn more about your methods. Thank you very much

Comment: Titus : When I added common  the following notification completed within
  for (final String url: urls) {}

The statement was notification first run. I'd just after finishing work loop notification can be output?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest compress data before inserting database.

```
//PreparedStatement.setBytes(1,compress(html));

public static byte[] compress(String str) throws Exception {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream obj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(obj);
    gzip.write(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    gzip.close();
    return obj.toByteArray();
} 

public static String decompress(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
    GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis,"UTF-8"));
    String outStr = "";
    String line;
    while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
        outStr += line;
    }
    return outStr;
}
```

Second way, save html data to a file and store only file path in database.

```
long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
String filePath = String.valueOf(ts)+".gz"; 
saveToFile(filePath ,html);
--------    
public static void saveToFile(String filePath, String text) {
    try {
        GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        gzos.write(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        gzos.finish();
        gzos.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think if split the list url into multiple Thread, the implementation will be faster.I see you are also interested in reading web pages, so try to think this subject with me