# Variable transmission values for threading in java

Tags: java, multithreading, jsoup

I want to know how to transmit values to Thread.
I want to Thread 1 show from 1-> 5
I want to Thread 2 show from 1-> 10

=>Through count variable.Please help me

```
public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThread myThread = new MyThread();

        myThread.setCount(10);
        Thread thread = new Thread(myThread);
        thread.start();

        myThread.setCount(5);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(myThread);
        thread2.start();
    }

}

class MyThread implements Runnable {

    int count = 0;

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\t\t" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

My idea is to split the list url and read the link I have them retrieved data to the database.It's too difficult for me please help
[Jsoup save content into the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193462/jsoup-save-content-into-the-database)

Comment: Create a new instance of `MyThread` for each thread otherwise you may change the `count` before the previous thread finishes running.

Comment: Thank you.Can you give me more detail how 2 :  you may change the count before the previous thread finishes running ?

Comment: If the first thread hasn't finished before you call `myThread.setCount(5);` it will no longer perform `10` iterations because you've changed it's `count` value from `10` to `5`

Comment: I understand thank you Titus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create 2 separate Thread objects, and set to each one the desired count.

```
MyThread t = new MyThread( );
t.setCount(10);
Thread t1 = new Thread(t);
t1.start( );

t = new MyThread( );
t.setCount(5);
Thread t2 = new Thread(t);
t2.start( );
```

In this way, each Thread object will run its own MyThread.run method, with the count you configured for each MyThread object.